# Android - SurfaceView (width, height) problem

Tags: android, height, width, surfaceview

Im new to android and im facing some issues...

Im using a SurfaceView to extend my class.
In my class i cant get width and height of the SurfaceView.
It is always 0. Im trying to flick an image on the entire screen (surfaceView) but im unable to get its width and height.

Any suggestions?

Here is the code for SurfaceView in main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <test.MyClass android:id="@+id/SurfaceView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </test.MyClass>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried similar thing and posted on this thread [Android: UI elements over canvas layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781738/android-ui-elements-over-canvas-layer/4781874#4781874)

Apart from above you would also need this to get height and width

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    this.canvas = canvas;

    if (!oneTime)
    {
        oneTime = true;
        screenWidth = getWidth();
        screenHeight = getHeight();
        Bitmap red = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
        red = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(red, screenWidth , screenHeight , true);
    }
}
```

if you dont want to pull your code in OnDraw you can try below code

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
```

But this will give you width height of whole visible area

Comment: thats abit too late. Before going into onDraw method im creating an image. I need to create the image with width and height. After that i render something in the image graphics and in onDraw i just do canvas.drawBitmap(image.getBitmap(), 0, 0, null);

Comment: why cant you create image in onDraw

Comment: must be a habbit from j2Me onPaint ... its not the same is it? :)

Comment: I have edited the code you cant try that one so that your image is not created everytime the ondraw is called

Comment: hmmm i tried to avoid implementing rendering in onDraw. I have 10 lines of code to render the image graphics. It didnt seem right to put all that into onDraw ... i will give it a try, tho i dont like the fact that i cant get SurfaceView width and height from outside onDraw method ...

Comment: i have stumbled across that code, but getWindowManager() is not recognised in my class that extends SurfaceView?

Answer (score 6):

You could try implementing the surfaceChanged method (which is called any time the surface is resized, including when it is initialized):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html#surfaceChanged(android.view.SurfaceHolder, int, int, int)

Just do:

```
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // do whatever you want here with width and height;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found worked for me with this was to use getHeight() and getWidth() inside my SurafaceCreated method, after I started my thread. This allowed me to have the Height and Width of the surface view before any updating or drawing has occured.

Answer (score 2):

Use `surfaceView.getHolder().getSurfaceFrame()` to get the `Rect` object with the sizes