# How to apply a similar style to my android application

Tags: java, android

I would like to create a similar look to t the below application.

Now if you look at the top of the image. The map seems to roll under the list of buttons at the top. The list of buttons seems to protude over the map.

How would i go about applying this style programmitcally in my application.

i would consider it to be similar to the bevel on a listview

[image: Activity view]

Comment: Would that not just be a layer on top of the map?

Comment: But im not looking for list of buttons on top of a map, it could also be an image or a webview

Answer (score 0):

I don't do android much but it looks like it might just be a .png with a dropshadow. Same with the popup in the middle

Answer (score 0):

In [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781738/android-ui-elements-over-canvas-layer), they asked how to add [UI elements over the canvas layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781738/android-ui-elements-over-canvas-layer). This might help you out to understand the XML layout used to the user interface.

Now from the android developer site, you might find the [UI Design Guidline section](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html) to be helpful in that it describes how menus and icons are created and dives down much deeper into the UI.

Good luck and hope this helps some.